# How to prevent double-click on refresh button

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-activity, android-button, android-menu

I'm developing an android app where i've a refresh button in my action bar. This button call a function that re-open the same activity. This activity contains an asyncTask to load the content.

At the moment i'm encountering this problem. When i click on the refresh button it works fine, but if i click on the refresh button when the AsyncTask is still working (i've a progress bar to check the status) the app crashes.

The error that i receive is: NullPointerException

Is it possible to disable that button until the activity (and its AsyncTask) are completely loaded?

Comment: Well all those solutions are good. disable the button while doin some work. Enable it again when it's done

Comment: Thanks to all! And if I would like to disable a menu item, how could i do?

Comment: item.disable(true) i guess. You can also replace it by a spinner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your button's `OnClickListener`, from where you execute the `AsyncTask`, add this code:

```
button.setEnabled(false);
```

In `onPostExecute()` method of your `AsyncTask`, place this:

```
button.setEnabled(true);
```

If you also give the 'cancel' option to the user(i.e. if you have overridden the `onCancelled()` method in your `AsyncTask`), enable the button in `onCancelled()`.

**Edit 1**:

Declare a `boolean` flag in your activity:

```
boolean menuButtonIsEnabled = true;
```

In your `OnClickListener`, set this flag to false:

```
menuButtonIsEnabled = false;
```

In `onPostExecute()` method of your `AsyncTask`:

```
menuButtonIsEnabled = true;
```

Override the `onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu)` method in your activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu (Menu menu){
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

    MenuItem button = menu.findItem(R.id.whatever_menu_button);

    if(menuButtonIsEnabled){
        button.setEnabled(true);
    } else {
        button.setEnabled(false);
    } 
    return true; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much vikram! And if I would like to disable a menu item, how could i do?

Comment: @Pepozzo See `Edit 1` above. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Again thank you! But i've a question using your solution in Edit 1: how could i call the OnPrepreOptionsMenu() in onPostExecute() in my AsyncTask to enable the menu item? Because at the moment the menu item is set disabled by default and it stays disabled also when the AsyncTask is completed even if i've added your code in onPostExecute().

Comment: @Pepozzo You don't have to call `OnPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu)`. You only set the boolean flag `menuButtonIsEnabled` to true. Let's see what happens: User clicks on the menu button --> `menuButtonIsEnabled` is set to false and the AsyncTask starts. When the user tries to click the menu button again, in `OnPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu)`, menu button is disabled. When the `AsyncTask` completes, `menuButtonIsEnabled` is set to true. If the user clicks the menu button now, menu button will be enabled. We are only setting flags here.

Comment: Ok, that's clear. My problem is that the menu item should be disabled by default because the activity loads an AsyncTask on onCreate. So, if i leave the menu item as enabled, the application could crash immediatly if an user click on refresh when AsyncTask in not completely loaded.

Comment: @Pepozzo If that's the case, then change the boolean flag's declaration from `boolean menuButtonIsEnabled = true;` to `boolean menuButtonIsEnabled = false;`.

Answer (score 1):

In your onClickListener, the first thing you do is deactivate the button. This way it cannot be clicked again until you reactivate it :

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View target) {
        target.setClickable(false);
        target.setEnbled(false);
        // Start your asynctask
    }
}
```

in your AsyncTask.onPostResult(), you can reactivate the click on the button.

Nota: setClickable(false) prevents the button from reacting to clicks events, but setEnabled(false) also usually changes the appearance of the button.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to **disable** the button from `onPreExecute` in `AsyncTask` and **enable** the button from `onPostExecute` in `AsyncTask`

Answer (score 0):

You can check the status of your task.... On click of refresh button...

```
if(yourAsyncTaskObject != null && yourAsyncTaskObject.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING){
         then start your activity again here
    }
```